# Fluid width logo over another image

Tags: css

I'll be placing an image [where the header currently is here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/advertise.html) and wanted the logo to still be positioned absolutely over it where it is now to the left, but to reduce with height:auto at fluid widths..

How would be the best way to do it? Do I need to give the image container a % width?  The middle banner is fluid, but for some reason I can't get the logo to reduce fluidly..

If someone could maybe check in an inspector? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use `width:100%` with `max-width: [width of img]` (and `height:auto`)

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wJMPG/)